# How to tart service remotely on Windows 10

Tags: windows, psexec, sc

I have tried several methods to start the service remotely but none of them work.

So, i try to start Windows Service (TeamViewer) from PC1 (192.168.1.10) on PC2 (192.168.1.20).
All PC are on Windows 10 Pro.

Ping 192.168.1.20 OK

RDP 192.168.1.20 OK

**CMD in mode Administrator**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>net use \\192.168.1.20 pass /USER:login
La commande s’est terminée correctement.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>net use
Les nouvelles connexions seront mémorisées.
État         Local     Distant                   Réseau
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK                     \\192.168.1.20\IPC$       Microsoft Windows Network
La commande s’est terminée correctement.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc \\192.168.1.20 query TeamViewer
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService échec(s) 5 :

Accès refusé.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc \\192.168.1.20 start TeamViewer
[SC] StartService: OpenService échec(s) 5 :

Accès refusé.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>psexec \\192.168.1.20 -u login -p pass start TeamViewer

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access 192.168.1.20:
AccÞs refusÚ.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>psservice \\192.168.1.20 -u 192.168.1.20\login -p pass start TeamViewer

PsService v1.20 - Service information and configuration utility
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error querying services on \\192.168.1.20:
AccÞs refusÚ.
Error opening TeamViewer on \\192.168.1.20:
AccÞs refusÚ.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>psservice \\192.168.1.20 -u 192.168.1.20\login -p pass start TeamViewer

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
C:\WINDOWS\system32>
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wmic /node:'192.168.1.20' /user:'192.168.1.20\login' /password:'pass' SERVICE WHERE CAPTION='TeamViewer' CALL STARTSERVICE
ERREUR :
Description = Accès refusé.


C:\WINDOWS\system32>psservice \\192.168.1.20 -u 192.168.1.20\login -p pass start TeamViewer

PsService v1.20 - Service information and configuration utility
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Error querying services on \\192.168.1.20:
AccÞs refusÚ.
Error opening TeamViewer on \\192.168.1.20:
AccÞs refusÚ.
```

**Powershell in mode Administrator**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Service -ComputerName 192.168.1.20 -Name Apache-ignite | Stop-Service -Force
>>
Get-Service : Impossible de trouver un service assorti du nom « Apache-ignite ».
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ Get-Service -ComputerName 192.168.1.20 -Name Apache-ignite | Stop-Ser ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Apache-ignite:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you log as an administrator for performing network actions? What happens if you try, being logged as a regular user?

Comment: I am having the same problem with the standard user

Answer (score 0):

Add registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
DWORD Value 1